# Internals of block operations

Tags: node

I am trying to understand the tezos block operations can any one shed some light on my queries.I have my own tezos node set up and trying to find the operations in a block using http://xxx/chains/main/blocks/417645/operations

1. result is an array [[endorsments],[2nd],[3rd],[transactions]] having 4 values/0-3-indexes and each value is again an array.first value is for endorsements and last valueis for transactions.2nd and 3rd values can any one help for which kind of operation

Comment: @Frank my query has some other parts as well whih are not answered in dupe

Comment: I suggest that you have different questions for each piece, they are all separate questions which requires details for each.